# Does CLLocationManager have a completion handler for startUpdatingLocation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get a users current location using `CLLocationManager`. It is all working fine however there is a bit of a delay while the app is finding the location and I need to wait for it to complete before allowing the user to send it. Is there some sort of completion handler for `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` of should I just use a BOOL variable to keep track of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CLLocationManagerDelegate method called

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```